# Feedback on Apple instruments tool

Tags: xcode-instruments

I was wondering if there are some video tutorials on using the instruments tool and / or good step by step tutorials with good illustrations.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has published the Instruments User Guide. It is accessible within the iPhone Developer Page: [Instruments User Guide:Instruments Quick Start](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)